# Set variable value using PyFMI

Tags: python

After loading a FMU I am trying to set the value of a variable before running the simulation using PyFMI.

I've tried using the .set() function but every time, the value returned is an array with one value, 0.

```
fmu_path = "./myfmu.fmu"
model = load_fmu(fmu=fmu_path)
model.set("my_var", 3.0)
```

When I do `model.get('my_var')` `array([0.])` is returned.